# Yii make trigger for actions

Tags: php, triggers, action, yii

Is any way to do something like that:
Triggers on action, that runnings before or after action, and in other folder.
For example folder
protected/triggers/CMainController.php
function actionAfterIndex() { ... }
Will calls after main action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are methods in CController for [beforeAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail) and [afterAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#afterAction-detail).
You're also able to determine the current action with their $action parameter.

```
protected boolean beforeAction(CAction $action)
```